# Writing tests for tensorflow

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow

I wanted to write a test for tf.metrics but I am confused about the project structure.

I followed the tensorflow instructions (installed docker) and tried to ran

```
sudo tensorflow/tools/ci_build/ci_build.sh CPU bazel test //tensorflow/python/ops/...
```

This executes succesfully but only runs the test in //tensorflow/python/ops/losses because (I assume) only the losses directoy has a proper build file.

So first question:
Why does the //tensorflow/python/ops/ directory not have a build file?

Second: How do I run all the tests in all the directories without adding BUILD files everywhere?

Third, looking through the directory it appears that almost every file has a matching _test file but the metrics.py and metrics_impl.py files do not have any. Does that mean there are currently **no** tests for tf.metrics?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked on Github and got an answer. The test files I was looking for are located in tensorflow/python/kernel_tests/metrics_test.py. Not sure why they are there but that answers the question.

Edit: Just learned that there is a second test file tensorflow/contrib/metrics/python/ops/metric_ops_test.py that also contains some of the tests.